# What condition does while(true) test? When is it true and false?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I do no understand why anybody would use

```
while(true) {
   //do something
}
```

instead of

```
boolean condition = true;
while(condition == true) {
   //do something
}
```

The latter is super easy to understand, whilst the former is not.

So, what condition does while(true) check? When is while(true) true, and when is it false?

Comment: old video games programming 101!

Comment: I don't understand why anybody would use `while(condition == true) {` instead of `while(condition) {`

Comment: Sometimes the exit condition from a loop is complicated, such as in a server that is expected to constantly wait for and process input, until it receives a signal to shut down. In such cases, `while (true)` (or its synonym, `for (;;)`) is sometimes used, and a `break` is performed when the exit condition finally occurs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is nonsensical.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> When is while(true) true, and when is it false?

It's always true, it's never false.

Some people use `while(true)` loops and then use `break` to exit them when a certain condition is true, but it's generally quite sloppy practice and not recommended. Without the use of `break`, `return`, `System.exit()`, or some other such mechanism, it will keep looping forever.

Comment: Is there any possible way it can be false?

Comment: @Gregg1989, please let me get this straight. You're asking if there's any way that true can be false?

Comment: @davmac Yes. Can a `while(true)` loop ever return false and not execute?

Comment: @Gregg1989, a while loop never 'returns' anything, either true or false. It repeatedly checks its condition and executes its body, so long as the condition remains true. Only when the condition becomes false does the while loop stop executing. In a `while(true)` loop the condition is `true`. `true` is never `false`, in any universe that I know of. If you are trolling, sir, then well played.

Comment: `true` is always `true`

Comment: 'true is never false, in any universe that I know of' - except maybe when using perl. I'm not sure about perl.

Answer (score 4):

Though we never know when we encounter a situation where we need it. We can also have infinite for loop.

```
for(;;) {//Code here}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a real world example. The while loop will iterate while the user input can't be parsed to an int. When the user input is parsed to int the loop exits by returning the number entered by the user.

```
private int getNumber(String message) {
    while (true) {  
        System.out.print(message);
        String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(userInput);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            System.out.printf("%s isn't a number!%n", userInput);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`condition == true` is also going to return a boolean which is 'true'.So using that directly instead of all that.

Answer (score 2):

`while(true)` loop will of course always iterate. You've to manually break out of it using `break`, or `System.exit()`, or may be `return`.

`while(condition == true)` will be true while `condition` is `true`. You can make that false by setting `condition = false`.

I would never ever use `while(condition == true)` at least. Instead just use `while (condition)`. That would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

while(true) is always true. Loop statements are executed all the time. If you have to break the loop, we have to use break statement.

Answer (score 1):

`while(true)` is used to for infinite loops. They will loop forever because `true` is ALWAYS `true` They are generally used when you have to do something until a certain condition is met. You then exit with the `break` statement

```
while(true) {
  //attempt to satisfy some condition

  if (satisfied) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use **While(true)** when i want to run a loop that does not have a specific case to stop. Of course you can declare some boolean condition, but in my case I want to make my code shorter.

**For example:** I create a Id number, and I want to check that Id in my database first to see whether it is existing or not. If yes, i create a new id and check again, we may create the existing Id again and again. I use this loop to make sure that the Id number is absolutely unique. If no, I break the loop.

```
    int myNewId = createNewId();

    while(true) {
       if (existingId(newId)) {
         myNewId = createNewId();
       }
       else break;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

1. List item

while(True):
   statement
   if(condition):
      break
This is only work in python 
In java you can write like that for same purpose

while(1==1)
{
Ststements...
}

Comment: It does not seem an answer for the specific program language the question is. Please, try to formulate a possible answer in  Java.