# java for loop with "true" as the stop condition?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a program I need to implement that has the following code:

```
for (int n = 1024; true; n+=n)
```

I cannot find any other examples of java loops having such a format.  What does this mean?  I've tried to research it, but I don't even know what to search for - it's totally foreign to me.

Comment: It means that the loop will run forever (give or take a `break` statement).

Comment: That makes sense, but it sounds very reckless!

Comment: [shrug] It's not reckless if that's what you need it to do.

Comment: From times to times, that could be necessary to have a loop going on forever until something happens, which could not be written as a condition, so the loop exits using `break` or `return`

Comment: Not reckless, this is how daemons work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What condition does while(true) test? When is it true and false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512830/what-condition-does-whiletrue-test-when-is-it-true-and-false)

Comment: Because the condition in a `for` loop is optional and defaults to `true`, you won't usually see an explicit `true`; you would see `for (int n = 1024; ; n+=n)`.

Comment: Not exactly on point but nevertheless interesting IMO is that a conventional way to comment out several lines in Tcl is to use an `if 0` block; see the section entitled "Block Comments" here: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/comment

Answer (score 0):

The basic for statement [is described in the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1):

> ```
> for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement
> ```

You are asking about the case when `Expression` is `true`. (The square brackets above mean it is optional).

The meaning of that is described just below, in [Sec 14.14.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1.2):

> - If the *Expression* is not present, or it is present and the value resulting from its evaluation (including any possible unboxing) is true, then the contained *Statement* is executed.
>
> ...
>
> - If the *Expression* is present and the value resulting from its evaluation (including any possible unboxing) is false, no further action is taken and the forstatement completes normally.

So, `Expression` is present, and evaluates to `true` (because `true` evaluates to `true`). Hence, `Statement` is executed, and will continue to be executed because `Expression` remains `true`.

As such, it is an infinite loop (unless there is a break, return, throw or `System.exit` inside the loop).

Answer (score -1):

Why you dont use another loop? Use for example do-while instead of

```
for (int n = 1024; true; n+=n)
```

You can make a work around with:

```
int n=1024;
do{ 
//your code
n+=n;
}while(condition==false);
```