# Need help intgerating a while loop in my java program. Want the program to handle incorrect input better

Tags: java, while-loop

This is my code so far that only works (displays the welcome message) when both a matching username and password have been entered.

I am unsure how to integrate a while loop that stops the user from progressing to the password stage if the usernameInput string does not match the username string, and loops over and over until the correct username has been entered. Then after I would like the same thing for the passwordInput string until it matches the password string. The idea is to have the program be able to loop over and over until the correct username AND password have been entered by the user.

[NOTE: I'm coming into java from a very basic knowledge of python, so everything may be a little disordered and inefficient]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String username,usernameInput, password, passwordInput;
        username= "KenBoneL0ver";
        password= "KenBone4Life";
        
        Scanner myObj1= new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Please enter your username:");
        usernameInput= myObj1.nextLine();
        
        if (!usernameInput.equals(username)) {    
            System.out.println("Incorrect username. Please try again:");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Now please enter the correct password:");
        }
        
        Scanner myObj2= new Scanner(System.in);
        
        passwordInput= myObj2.nextLine();
        
        if (!passwordInput.equals(password)) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect password. Please try again:");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You have successfully logged in!"); 
        }
        
        myObj1.close();
        myObj2.close();
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Create a while loop that continues while a Boolean variable is false and then set that variable to true inside the loop as soon as both a correct username and password have been given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check if are you looking for something like this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myObj1 = null;
        try {
            String username, usernameInput, password, passwordInput;
            username = "KenBoneL0ver";
            password = "KenBone4Life";

            myObj1 = new Scanner(System.in);

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Please enter your username:");
                usernameInput = myObj1.nextLine();
                if (!usernameInput.equals(username)) {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect username. Please try again:");
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }

            while (true) {
                // Scanner myObj2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Now please enter the correct password:");
                passwordInput = myObj1.nextLine();

                if (!passwordInput.equals(password)) {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect password. Please try again:");
                    continue;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You have successfully logged in!");
                    break;
                }
            }

            // myObj2.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (myObj1 != null) {
                myObj1.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter your username:
test
Incorrect username. Please try again:
Please enter your username:
KenBoneL0ver
Now please enter the correct password:
test
Incorrect password. Please try again:
Now please enter the correct password:
KenBone4Life
You have successfully logged in!
```

Comment: My main goal was to replicate something I had done in python in the past, however after looking up support for this I struggled to wrap my head around java's way of handling user input. However your edits are exactly what I was looking to do. Thank you very much. You don't happen to know of any good resources for beginners where "try", "continue", "break" keywords are explained?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop:

```
while (someBooleanCondition) {
    statement(s);
}
```

When both conditions are true (password and username) then the boolean condition breaks the while loop and tells the user they have successfully logged in.

[Here is a link that may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512830/what-condition-does-whiletrue-test-when-is-it-true-and-false)

Answer (score 0):

You can use assignment operator when checking the condition inside `while`:
`while (!username.equals(usernameInput = scan.nextLine()))`.  Then you won't need any extra boolean variables and/or `break`/`continue` statements to implement necessary flow.

Aside comments related to the use of `Scanner`:

1. there's no need to create a separate instance to input username and password.
2. It's good to see that you cared for closing both `Scanner` instances.  However, using `try-with-resources` construction guarantees that the resource implementing `AutoCloseable` interface will be closed automatically.

That being said, the code may be rewritten as follows:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String 
            username = "user",
            password = "pswd",
            usernameInput, 
            passwordInput;
        
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your username:");
            while(!username.equals(usernameInput = scan.nextLine())) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect username. Please try again:");
            }
            
            System.out.println("Now please enter the correct password:");
            while(!password.equals(passwordInput = scan.nextLine())) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect password. Please try again:");
            }
            System.out.println("You have successfully logged in!");
        }
    }
}
```